# Firebase Authentication Logcat error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, oop

I'm attempting to create a LogIn and SignUp system using Firebase on Android Studio, I've also added the option for the user to log on using Facebook and Google, both of which are working fine. The LogIn and SignUp system however, I've been running into trouble with.

I've been trying to figure out the solution for this for about 2 days, as I have browsed around and attempted to apply solutions to similar problems that I have encountered before, but to no avail.

From my understanding, the code I've written is attempting to take the value of the EditText but fails, since it is still empty during launch thus, resulting in the crash.

Here is the MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
    private lateinit var callbackManager: CallbackManager

    private lateinit var editTextEmail: EditText
    private lateinit var editTextPassword: EditText
    private lateinit var buttonReg: MaterialButton
    private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var confirmTextPassword: EditText

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.email)
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword)
        //confirmTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.cfPassword)
        buttonReg = findViewById(R.id.login_btn)
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        var textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.registerNow)

        var email: String = editTextEmail.text.toString()
        var password: String = editTextPassword.text.toString()
        var btnSubmit: MaterialButton = findViewById(R.id.login_btn)

        EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password)
        confirmTextPassword.text.toString()

        buttonReg.setOnClickListener {
            val email: String = editTextEmail.text.toString().trim()
            val password: String = editTextPassword.text.toString().trim()

            if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Email and password cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                // Proceed with creating the EmailAuthCredential
                val credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password)

                // Continue with your authentication logic here
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success")
                            toast("Login Successful.")
                            Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java).apply {
                                startActivity(this)
                                finish()
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                            toast("Authentication failed.")
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

        textView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, SignUpActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }


        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.registerNow).setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, SignUpActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success")
                        toast ("Login Successful.")

                    Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
                    finish()
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.exception)

                        toast ("Authentication failed.")
                }
            }

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener () {
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        Log.d(Logging.TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success")
                        val user = auth.currentUser

                        toast ("Account successfully created!")
                    } else {
                        Log.w(Logging.TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.exception)

                        toast ("Authentication failed.")
                    }
                }
        }

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.nav_home), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

        findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.googleSigninBtn).setOnClickListener {
            signInGoogle()

            val facebookSigninBtn: MaterialButton = findViewById(R.id.facebookSigninBtn)
            facebookSigninBtn.setOnClickListener {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, listOf("public_profile"));
            }

            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

            callbackManager = create()

            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                    override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, HomeActivity::class.java))
                        finish()
                    }

                    override fun onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    override fun onError(exception: FacebookException) {
                        // App code
                    }
                })

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(applicationContext)
        }
    }
    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        if (currentUser != null) {
            val intent : Intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
            finish()
        }
    }

    private fun toast(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    private fun signInGoogle(){
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        launcher.launch(signInIntent)
    }

    private val launcher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
                handleResults(task)
            }
        }

    private fun handleResults(task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        if (task.isSuccessful){
            val account: GoogleSignInAccount? = task.result
            if (account != null) {
                updateUI(account)
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, task.exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }

    private fun updateUI(account: GoogleSignInAccount?) {
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account?.idToken, null)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener{
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                val intent : Intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
                if (account != null) {
                    intent.putExtra("email", account.email)
                }
                if (account != null) {
                    intent.putExtra("name", account.displayName)
                }
                startActivity(intent)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, it.exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

EDIT: Below you'll find the content_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below you'll find the Logcat:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.navotasapp, PID: 12865
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.navotasapp/com.example.navotasapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
> at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.2.0:2)
> at com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.3.0:1)
> at com.example.navotasapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:74)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

I've tried applying solutions I've seen on Github and here on StackOverflow, including moving the variables into the .setOnClickListener, declaring email and password as class level variables, as well as consulting ChatGPT, but I still can't get seem to find the appropriate solution.

I apologize if this may seem to be a noob question, as I am only a beginner in Android Studio, and programming.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the exact line of code that throws that exception?

Comment: Hi! 

File: MainActivity.kt

Line: 74

Exception Type: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Exception Message: Given String is empty or null                                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty

Comment: What exactly is at line 74?

Comment: That would be EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password)

Comment: Two identical tines of code contain `EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password)`? Which one is at line 74?

Comment: The one above of `buttonReg.setOnClickListener` would be line 74. For reference, `buttonReg.setOnClickListener` would be at line 77.

Comment: It looks like you're passing email/password empty or null. Try to replace them with hardcoded values and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Can you also please share the XML file where you have those EditTexts? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo apologies for the late reply, here is the XML file --> https://traff.co/ltKqUDOS

Comment: @AbdullahJaved that didn't quite work, I tried adding hardcoded Strings for `email` and `password` but it still resulted in the crash.

Comment: Please don't provide external links, just edit your question and add the code.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply @AlexMamo. I've edited the post to suit your needs. Please let me know if there's anything else you require.

Comment: I cannot see any EditTexts in your code.